# My C# app always queried data from a SQL database, now suddenly it doesn't return data anymore

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# app that queries a SQL database on a server, I have tested it loads of times, but today the query didn't return any data, the app and the database is still the same. No changes.

DO you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: Another developer accidentally executed his `TRUNCATE TABLE` command on your table?

Comment: i am getting data out of the database to add to a XML file that I send to a web service.

Comment: I went onto SQL Server Manager to see if the data is still in the Database, and its all there.

Answer (score 3):

Something had to have changed. Either the query changed or the data changed. Or perhaps security changed. I'd say start by running SQL Server Profiler. This will let you see all queries that are hitting the database server and who is running them. This is a great way to debug problems like this. If the query looks right, try logging-in to SQL Server Management Studio with the same credentials as the C# app and manually running the query you see in SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: hi! thanx, Ill try this right now, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to start basic.  Debug and step through your code, query the database directly from SSMS to see if you get the same result set.  Have you got a try...catch around your sql connection, sql query etc?

You need to provide a bit more information than it's just not working.  Copy and paste the code your trying to use, as well as the some sample db content.

Comment: Have you run the same query that your using in your code in a query window against the db?  Something has to of changed, things don't just stop working for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of small changes that could cause the code to stop working. If the culture settings on the server has changed for example, it could parse date strings differently and don't recognise the format that you use.

There are ways to make the application less sensetive to such small changes, like specifying the culture when you parse data that is culture dependant.

Normally you would either get a correct result or an error message. Check so that you don't have any `try...catch` that is swallowing error message without giving any indication that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check your sql server wheather it is working from configuration manager.

Comment: Its working perfectly, do you know of any setting that could have changed?